# Parse CLP / ACL causing issues with beforeSave trigger

Tags: security, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

thanks for stopping by.

I have a class, let's call Class1, that I use to give users of my app discounts / coupons. When a user finishes the registration process, I create an object and store the pointer to it on the user.

I want to give this class CLP permissions so that the public can create, but not write to this object. Let it only be something that I use internally.

My problem is that the class has several arrays that can't be undefined, or other cloud functions will end up throwing errors trying to read those values. I set up a beforeSave() trigger for the class, and use the master key, but the object isn't being saved so my entire user save at the end of registration isn't working. How do I fix this while keeping my object secure and making sure users can't steal all of my app's services for free?

Here is my beforeSave trigger:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Class1", function(request, response)
{
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var emptyArray = [];
    class1 = request.object;
    if( class1.isNew() )
    {
        class1.set("array1", emptyArray);
        class1.set("array2", emptyArray);
        class1.set("array3", emptyArray);
    }
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: Do you see the object data being created in the log ? Any error messages ?

Comment: Could you get rid of the arrays entirely? Rather than having an array of coupon pointers stored within user, just have a user pointer associated with each coupon. As a general rule of thumb, I've found it's best to keep the user class as minimal as possible

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you can't use the master key to override CLP / ACL stuff in a beforeSave trigger... though it makes sense, as that would entirely defeat the point.

However, if you give public create access, you can populate any initial data, you just can't update it without update access. So, the obvious answer was to just set these parameters on the client side when I created the object and before I saved it.